# Submodule generated by $2\otimes x - x \otimes 2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensors

Let $ I = (2, x)$ be an ideal of $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$. I want to show that the submodule generated by the element $2\otimes x - x\otimes 2 $ of $I \otimes_R I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

The first step of the problem was to show that $2\otimes x - x\otimes 2$ is torsion, which I did by noticing that
$$2x(2\otimes x - x\otimes 2) = 2x\otimes 2x - 2x\otimes 2x = 0$$
But I don't see how that is related to showing the isomorphism. How can I use this fact to show the desired isomorphism?

Comment: Why don't show that 2 and x (separatedly) annihilate thar element? In fact, a cyclic module is isomorphic to the ring over the annihilator and Z_2 is exactly Z[x]/(2,x).

Comment: Doesn't $2\otimes x=2x\otimes 1=x\otimes 2$?

Comment: @Berci Wouldn't that imply that I = (2, x) contains 1?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, $1\notin I$, I said nothing..

Comment: @Berci, I still think it's good to consider that computation, since it might seem that we can compute $2\otimes x$ in $I\otimes_R I$ inside $R\otimes_R R$, etc.